# IBM APIC: apic commands not working

Tags: apiconnect

I am using API Connect: v5.0.4.0 (apiconnect: v2.3.6) on Windows 10 
I am getting the following exception when trying to use CLI commands with Developer toolkit.

```
E:\nodejs\ThinkIBM\inventory>apic create --type model
Error: Cannot find module 'arrify'

E:\nodejs\ThinkIBM\inventory>apic loopback:relation
Error: Cannot find module 'arrify'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the above problem.
Run the following npm commands from your root **node.js** directory to fix the issue.

```
npm install --save arrify
npm install --save strip-dirs
```